# Add to the front of a list, the same element which is found at the end of the list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog but finding it very difficult. I am having trouble adding an element which is found at the end of a list, to the front of the list. So far all I can manage to do is to remove the element and put it at the front, however, I don't want to remove it, I want it to stay at the back plus add an instance of it to the front.

I have tried reviewing similar questions but I am still stuck.

I know I am going about it the wrong way, but here is what I have so far:

```
addLastToFront([], []).
addLastToFront(L, [H|T]) :- append(T, [H], L).
```

Which produces:

```
 ?- addLastToFront([a,b,c,d], X) --> ([d,a,b,c])
```

What I am trying to do:

```
?- addLastToFront([a,b,c,d], X) --> ([d,a,b,c,d])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWI Prolog has a `last(L, X)` which succeeds if `X` is the last element of `L`.

Armed with that predicate, you can easily define your needed predicate `last_as_first(L, [X|L])` to be *`[X|L]` is the list formed from the last element of list `L` used also as the head **if** `X` is the last element of `L`*. Which written in Prolog is:

```
last_as_first(L, [X|L]) :- last(L, X).
```

If you want to use `append/3`, you can define `last(L, X)` as `append(_, [X], L)`.

```
last_as_first(L, [X|L]) :- append(_, [X], L).
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, the append is easier for me to understand. Hopefully, I can get the hang of Prolog eventually. A shame I am not allowed to upvote yet.

Comment: @codiearher glad it helped. Bot the `append` and `last` versions mean the same  thing: that `X` is the last  member of `L`. Youccept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
list([])     --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).

concatenation([]) --> [].
concatenation([List|Lists]) -->
        list(List),
        concatenation(Lists).
```

You can use this DCG from https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg and then query:

```
?-List1 =[a,b,c],phrase(concatenation([Front,[Last]]),List1),List2 = [Last|List1].
Front = [a, b],
Last = c,
List1 = [a, b, c],
List2 = [c, a, b, c];
```